# How to give relative path for a file in xml file

Tags: xml, windows, scheduled-tasks

I am basically scheduling a task in task scheduler through xml file. My question is how we give relative path to the exe which is scheduled as a task in task scheduler.
[image: Screenshot of my xml file]

how can we give relative path to xml under `<command>`.
because i want to run this on other systems as well.

Comment: Do not convert text into pixels.

Comment: You can define a working directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskschedulerschema-exectype-complextype

Comment: @ceving I am not understanding kindly can you explain your answer?

Comment: My issue is that I don't want to give absolute path in the highlighted area I need a dynamic path. xml file pick this exe file on runtime.

Comment: I am sending this exe `sectel.exe` with my app and also this xml file i just want that this xml file picked it from client's machine and run it as scheduled task. Let's suppose this exe file is storing in appdata folder so how i update my xml file that it automatically picked it up and execute it?

Comment: The scheduler looks either in the specified working directory, in the absolute path or in the system PATH. Your installation needs to make sure, that one of the three matches.